# mice and mystics rules clarification

Tags: mice-and-mystics

We played chapter 3 of Mice and Mystics.

We defeated Brodie on a tile who appeared as the result of the special surge.

On the next tile, the clock wheel was again full of cheese and the special surge was again Brodie. Should he appear again, even if he has been defeated just before ?

Also, when a mouse or a minion attacks and there is no sword or bow appearing on the dice, is it necessary for the opponent to defend ? (and to obtain possibly some cheese).

Finally, after the dice game, if no rats were defeated, do we agree that 2 elite rats and 3 regular rats are on the tile ?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend breaking this up into 3 separate questions, which would help searchers to find specific answers better and help with keeping answers 'on topic'. That being said, here's what I know about these 3:

'Defeating' Brodie doesn't mean he's dead, it just means you made him leave the area. So you poked him a few times, he ran off to (literally) lick his wounds, and then came back in the next tile for revenge. So yes, it is entirely possible for you to encounter Brodie in a tile, defeat him, and then on the next tile encounter Brodie 2: Brodie's Revenge.

In the rule book under Battle: Melee Attack (pages 10 & 11), it instructs you to roll your attack and (Emphasis mine):

> Add the number of sword and sword/shield symbols rolled for that attack. This is the number of hits the mouse has inflicted.
>
> **If a mouse inflicted one or more hits**, the player to the left of the active player rolls defense for the targeted minion and adds the number of sword/shield results rolled.

So you only roll defense dice if one or more hits are rolled. No free cheese!

Your last question isn't ringing any bells, but it has been a couple of months since I've played M&M, so I might just need to pull out the scenario book when I get home, but if you could clarify it a bit here it might jog my memory and I could edit this and answer that one as well.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your answers. Should I edit the post and create 3 separate ones ? As for the third question, in the chapter 3, when the mice enters one tile, they see a group of rats playing a dice game. If they are equipped with the disguise, they can lure the rats and play the game with them.